# Force dhclient to always provide a unique IP from the available pool

Tags: ip, dhcpd, renew

I'm running RHEL 7.4 and the dhcpd is controlled by DD-WRT off my router.

Tried to use:

dhclient -r; dhclient -x; rm -f /var/lib/dhclient.leases; ip a; dhclient -v

but it either returns the same IP or one of two IP's.  I couldn't get it to return anything more.  I did check the dhcpd configuration I've done and the range is as defined: 192.168.0.100-255 .

I need dhclient to assign a different IP from the DHCP pool each time I run it.

How could I achieve that?  The only way I can think of doing so is by running nmap on the subnet to determine what IP's are free but that will have it's own shortcomings.

Cheers,

Comment: There's very little support we can provide for DD-WRT, which is where you would have to make any changes as it's your DHCP server.

Comment: If I run my own DHCPD server, what would you guys advise?

Comment: Can I configure a standard DHCPD to always return a unique IP, regardless of the same MAC being used?